# How can I partitioned may SEAGATE hard drive on Ubuntu 14.40 LTS?

Tags: partitioning

I have HP 630 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS. Yestarday, I buy an 1 TB Seagate external HDD . Now I want to make partition the HDD with 200 GB volume each ( 200*5 = 1 TB). How can I do this . See, in the **New partition** tab is inactive. Now how can I do this . Plz advice me. Thnanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to unmount the drive by right clicking the ntfs partition and click unmount.[image: Unmount] Then you will be able to shrink the current partition or delete the drive and make the new ones you want.
[image: controls].

Edit:: To rename the dive you right click the dive and click label.[image: labal], then a popup windows will appear and there is where you can set the drive name.[image: rename] 
 You can also rename each partition that way as well if you can

Comment: I want to rename my drive , but while **right click**  ,rename option is inactive. Is there any way out to rename the same ? plz rply.

Comment: @BapiSaha I have edited the answer with how. The partitions that you want to rename needs to be unmounted as well

Comment: @BapiSaha If that answered the question will you click the check mark to let people know this answer is what you needed